# Firebase, AngularFire - How to migrate an existing app that makes heavy use of arrays to angularFire

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I said it mostly in my title.

But I have an existing application that makes heavy use of arrays, now if I want to sync those arrays with angularFire to a firebase backend, when syncing it turns them all to objects thus making any array operations I've done around a significantly large applications return errors.

What is the cleanest way to introduce these technologies to an existing app.

Comment: Is it that you simply can't do any data modeling within an application without thinking about firebase as your backend solution first?

Comment: What error do you get? And can you create a small piece of code that reproduces the problem? Without those, it will be almost impossible to help you.

Comment: IMHO angularFire made a bad choice not implementing returned items as array's.

Answer (score 1):

AngularFire uses objects at the top-level, but you can always include arrays as children of a top-level objects and retain them as arrays.

For example:

```
$scope.topLevel = $firebase(new Firebase(URL));
$scope.topLevel.secondLevel = [1, 2, 3, 4];
$scope.topLevel.$save();
```

Will retain the array at URL + '/secondLevel'.